# Integral should not be continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral

I'm looking for a counter-example:

Let $f:[0,1]\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be continuous in such a way that

$$F(x):=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,t) dt$$

defines a function $F:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ (so in particular the integral is finite).

I'm looking for an $f$ such that $F$ is not continuous (it's enough if $F$ is discontinuous in one point, for example $0$).

Comment: The assumption: "$f:[0,1]\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be continuous in such a way that
$$F(x):=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x,t) dt$$ defines a function $F$ on $[0,1]$", Not enough to guarantee the existence of such $F$. $f$ should be bounded as $t\to \pm \infty$.

Comment: @mwomath My "in such a way" means that I consider only such $f$ which give rise to a function $F:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: Set $g(y) = \frac{1}{1+y^2}$ (so $\int_\mathbb{R} g(y) dy = \pi$) and then
$$
f(x,t) = \begin{cases} g\left(t - \frac{1}{1-2x}\right) \quad (x < \frac{1}{2}) \\
0 \quad (x \ge \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases} .
$$ 
It's not hard to see that $f$ is continuous.
Then $F(x) = \pi$ for $x < \frac{1}{2}$ and $F(x) = 0$ for $x \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

The effect occurs because $f(x,t) \to 0$ for all $t$ as $x \to \frac{1}{2}$, but the integral does not converge (Lebesgue's Theorem cannot be applied).